# Unable to change color of a shape layer made with Pen tool in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, shapes, path

I have selected the Pen tool and switched to shape (from path), I have then designed an arc like shape (C looking). The layer icon has the shape symbol like ordinary shapes made with the shape tool.

Now if I try to change the shape color it allows me to change it for ordinary shapes but not for the one made with Pen tool, yet it has the same layer icon/type of other shapes, I'm confused.

What am I doing wrong??

I noticed that the issue is due to not selecting fill color in the shape but only a border color, so since it has no fill I cannot use this method. Now the question is: how do I change the border color (track) of a shape made using the Pen tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the fill and stroke from the options bar at the top (with your shape layer selected and one of the shape tools or the Pen tool active)...

[image]